# Jquery Webcam Problems Displaying WebCam On Page

Tags: html, jquery-plugins

I am trying to get the webcam on the page to capture a photo, i am using [jquery web plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/). I am getting the following error in the web console: [16:00:48.593] TypeError: $(...).webcam is not a function......

**Html:**

```
    <head>

    <!-- <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script> --> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style>
        <%@ include file="../css/forms.css" %>
        <%@ include file="../css/citizen_registration.css" %>
        <%@ include file="../js/jQuery-webcam/jquery.webcam.js" %>

    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){


        $("#camera").webcam({
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                mode: "callback",
                swffile: "../js/jQuery-webcam/jscam_canvas_only.swf",    


                onLoad: function() {
                alert('HELLO');

                }


        }); 
 });


    <div id="camera"></div>
```

Comment: Why are including the JS file inside `<style>` element? Fix that and it will probably work.

Comment: Now i am getting [16:26:48.105] GET http://localhost:8084/js/jQuery-webcam/jscam_canvas_only.swf [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 10ms] and the file is in the correct directory and i have all other files there

Comment: Is this path accessible from the client? You are using `include file` which is executed on the server side. You have to put the file somewhere where it can be accessed form the client via an HTTP request, i.e. you should be abel to access the file if you just copy and paste the URL in your browser.

Comment: it is an accessible path. I have other files in there that's accessed by the application. I am going to create a swf directory just for .swf files and see if that works.

Comment: Ok great this worked needed the file to be outside my WEB-INF directory